# Pyqt5 Qgraphicsview scaled appropriately on load

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have some QGraphicItems that are being loaded in at multiple predetermined X and Y coordinates. I have a function that is called `fitInView` and when the user clicks a button to call that function the view is scaled just fine, but If I try to call that function during loading It does not scale how I would like. I believe it has something to do with how I am determining the scale factor. When I print out the values of the width and height of the viewport on load and when the user clicks the button, they are very different.

My question is how do I get the objects to be at the same scaled on load as they are when the user clicks the button. Thank you for your help.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()
        self.fitInView()

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

            print('viewrect.width: '+str(viewrect.width()))
            print('scenerect.width: '+str(scenerect.width()))
            print('viewrect.height: '+str(viewrect.height()))
            print('scenerect.height: '+str(scenerect.height()))

    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(self.ScrollHandDrag)
        # self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Fit Into View')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.fitPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        self.viewer.fitInView()

    def fitPoints(self):
        self.viewer.fitInView()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instant before the QGraphicsView is displayed, internal elements are recalculated so that you observe a different behavior, so the solution is to apply the function a moment after it is displayed. for this there are at least 2 options:

**1. QTimer.singleShot(0, ...):**

```py
# ...
self.setPoints()
QTimer.singleShot(0, self.fitInView)
# ...
```

**1. override showEvent method of Viewer**

```py
def showEvent(self, event):
    self.fitInView()
    super(Viewer, self).showEvent(event)
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you for the explanation of what is going on with the QGraphicsView internal elements.

Comment: Which one is worked for you.. i face the same issue..